# Matplotlib deprecation warning running through Ubuntu application

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm running a program through shell on Windows and keep getting this deprecation warning. Here is the code being ran and the error message:

Code:

```py
class Window:
    """Window to draw a gridworld instance using Matplotlib"""

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.fig = None
        self.imshow_obj = None

        # Create the figure and axes
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

        # Show the env name in the window title
        self.fig.canvas.set_window_title(title)

        # Turn off x/y axis numbering/ticks
        self.ax.set_xticks([], [])
        self.ax.set_yticks([], [])

        # Flag indicating the window was closed
        self.closed = False

        def close_handler(evt):
            self.closed = True

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', close_handler)
```

Output:

```
/home/msaidi/gym-minigrid/gym_minigrid/window.py:31: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Passing the minor parameter of set_xticks() positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.2; the parameter will become keyword-only two minor releases later.
  self.ax.set_xticks([], [])
/home/msaidi/gym-minigrid/gym_minigrid/window.py:32: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Passing the minor parameter of set_yticks() positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.2; the parameter will become keyword-only two minor releases later.
  self.ax.set_yticks([], [])
```

When I run the code in the IDE I don't get any errors.

I tried changing from `self.ax.set_xticks` to `set_xticks` and to `ax.set_xticks` and `self.set_xticks` and didn't work.

Tool info:

- Matplotlib version: 3.2.1
- Python 3
- Running through Ubuntu Windows application

Answer (score 18):

You need to separate tick values and tick labels.

```
ax.set_xticks([]) # values
ax.set_xticklabels([]) # labels
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to:

```
self.ax.set_xticks([])
self.ax.set_yticks([])
```

The error says that the second parameter cannot be given positionally, meaning that you need to explicitly give the parameter name minor=False for the second parameter or remove the second parameter in your case.